# Weird behaviour about the order of template alias and user defined operator

Tags: c++, clang++, name-lookup, template-aliases

The following piece of code can be compiled using MSVC(v19.38), but failed with GCC(13.2) and Clang(17.0.1). But older version of GCC, e.g. 11.2, works fine.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

#ifdef MY_INT
template<typename T, T V> struct my_int
{
        static constexpr T value = V;
        using value_type = T;
        constexpr operator value_type() const noexcept { return value; }
        constexpr value_type operator()() const noexcept { return value; }
};
template<auto V> using constant_int_t = my_int<decltype(V), V>;
#else
template<auto V> using constant_int_t = std::integral_constant<decltype(V), V>;
#endif

template<typename T1, typename T2>
using add_t = decltype(T1{} + T2{});

template<typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr auto operator+(T1, T2)
{
    return constant_int_t<T1::value + T2::value>{};
}

using v1 = constant_int_t<1>;
using v2 = constant_int_t<2>;
using v3 = add_t<v1, v2>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<v3, constant_int_t<3>>);
```

Clang complains about `v3` is of type int, which might be ascribed to it fails to spot the `operator+` defined after termplate alias `add_t` and performed an implicit type conversion when dealing with the adding.

If I use my own type of constant int (`my_int<T,V>`, which is almost the same as `std::integral_constant<T,V>`), clang will compile it. If I swap the order of definition of `add_t` and `operator+`, it also works fine.

So, is this a bug of Clang and GCC? Or an unspecified behaviour?

Comment: Just swap `operator+` and `add_t` so operator is actually declared when used inside of decltype.

Comment: @user7860670 is right, putting `operator+` before `add_t` [works](https://godbolt.org/z/7Yed84f69).

Comment: clang version ?

Comment: gcc reports assertion failure too:  https://godbolt.org/z/MYG1MsEr1 or works everywhere when `my_int` is used. So can't reproduce (different error or no error depending on build options). Maybe be you should specify compiler versions and all build flags.

Comment: @alfC clang version 14.0.0

Comment: @MarekR Switch the gcc version to 11.2 and it compiles https://godbolt.org/z/3KKxddqTE

Comment: Since new GCC also rejects this, I suggest editing the question to reflect this.

Comment: Better godbolt to demo all corner cases: https://godbolt.org/z/zGG84evEx - last answer shows that clang and new gcc are right to show an error (ADL kicks in).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `my_int`, the `::` (global) namespace is an associated namespace (since `my_int` is defined in the `::` namespace), so `auto ::operator+(T1, T2);` can be found via ADL.

If you use `std::integral_constant<int, x>`, the only associated namespace is `std`. Therefore, `operator+` is looked up in the `std::` namespace for ADL, which doesn't find anything that applies (so the builtin `int operator+(int, int)` is used after converting the arguments)

If you moved the `operator+` definition before `add_t`, it can be found via ordinary/non-ADL lookup.

Comment: I was planing to write about ADL too. Problme is I can't find sources which shows that ADL can ignore order of declarations and without ADL order is important.

Comment: I think the name-lookup should be performed at the point of specialization of template alias, at which my `::operator+(T1, T2)` can be found. Since templates will not turn into real 'code' before its specialization. But this is just me speculating how template works.

Comment: @qzhong The answer is correct. Templates can only see functions declared prior to their definitions, except for ADL, which can find functions declared anywhere. Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Template_definition *"Since templates will not turn into real 'code' before its specialization."* Compilers will generally "half-bake" a template when they first see the definition (try to check for some errors that can be detected without instantiaton, but how much is checked varies per compiler).

Comment: @MarekR Here's the source ^

Comment: Thanks. This explains a lot details which I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a bug of Clang.

[[temp.alias]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.alias#2.sentence-1):

> When a template-id refers to the specialization of an alias template, it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by substitution of its template-arguments for the template-parameters in the defining-type-id of the alias template.

So

```
using v3 = add_t<v1, v2>;
```

should be equivalent to

```
using v3 = decltype(v1{} + v2{});
```

But Clang treats them as different types.

---

Note that alias templates, unlike all other kinds of templates, are formally not subject to template instantiation. Therefore, in my opinion, the fact that only ADL (argument-dependent lookup) is performed at the point of instantiation is irrelevant here.

[[basic.lookup.argdep]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#4.sentence-3):

> If the lookup is for a dependent name, [argument-dependent] lookup is also performed from each point in the instantiation context of the lookup [...]

[[temp.spec.general]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec.general#1.sentence-1) (note the omission of "alias template"):

> The act of instantiating a function, a variable, a class, a member of a class template, or a member template is referred to as *template instantiation*.

[[temp.dep.candidate]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.candidate#1) (which IMO is not applicable to alias templates because they are not instantiated):

> If a dependent call would be ill-formed or would find a better match had the lookup for its dependent name considered all the function declarations with external linkage introduced in the associated namespaces in all translation units, not just considering those declarations found in the template definition and template instantiation contexts, then the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: This is wrong, see the other answer.

Comment: Well, I will interpret the standard as you do. But another answer seems more definitive, especially with this sentence from cppreference: _...The binding to the declarations made at that point is not affected by declarations visible at the point of instantiation._

Comment: @cpplearner There was a now-deleted comment that it's possible that function calls in `using` always bind late, when it's used. That's an interesting idea. Do you no longer think that's true?